# Basic Pointers in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I have three difference examples mention below. I don't understand why ex1 has same output for ex2 and differ output for ex3, also why ex2 is not the same as ex3 where I just make a creation in another line!!

**ex1**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int x=2;
    int *y;
    y = &x;
    printf("value: %d\n", *y);
    printf("address: %d\n", y);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**output**

```
value: 2
address: 2686744
```

**ex2**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int x=2;
    int *y = &x;
    printf("value: %d\n", *y);
    printf("address: %d\n", y);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**output**

```
value: 2
address: 2686744
```

**ex3**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int x=2;
    int *y;
    *y = &x;
    printf("value: %d\n", *y);
    printf("address: %d\n", y);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**output**

```
value: 2686744
address: 2130567168
```

**I HAVE BIG MISUNDERSTANDING OF POINTERS WHEN I THINK STAR MUST BECOME WITH (y) NOT (int)
AND I FIGURE OUT THAT STAR WITH (int) NOT (y) (^_^)
NOW EVERYTHING IS CLEAR FOR ME... THANKS FOR ALL YOUR ANSWERS**

Comment: Turn up your compiler warning level, and you should be told about the problem...

Comment: ex3 is not valid.  If `y` was never set you cannot take `*y`.

Comment: Also you should get in the habit of using `%p` when printing pointers, not `%d`.  (But still use `%d` for integer types like `*y`.)

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth I want to understanding that in memory level not as compiler said, which is not enough information for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In example 3, you first declare a pointer:

```
int *y;
```

and then you say that the `int` value of `*y` is the address of `x`.

That's because with the declaration `int *y` you have:

- `y` is of type `int *`
- `*y` is of type `int`.

So, the right lines of code in example 3 should be:

```
int *y;
y = &x;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. so I have to give y address of x, but if I don't the compiler will asign to y a random value. is my explanation correct?

Comment: No, it's not a random value. With `*y = &x` you are getting the integer representation of the address of `x`.

Comment: in ex3 when I print y. why I got this value 2130567168? what that value represented for?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, lets bring everything in one line:

```
int *y
ex1:    y = &x
ex2:    y = &x
ex3: (*y) = &x
```

Ex3 is different from the other two.

Ex3 is assigning the value (&x) to the value pointed-to by the pointer y.

Comment: thanks for your answer. so if I write "int *y = &x;" that's mean value of y is address of x. is that correct ?

Comment: @thalsharif: Basically yes, but this was valid only if y was of type `int**`, and y did actually point to something (which it doesn't)

Answer (score 1):

Because the third example says `*y =` instead of `y =`

Answer (score 1):

```
*y
```

is used to know the content of the adress pointed by `y`

Answer (score 1):

`int *y; *y = &x;` is different from `int *y = &x;`. In the former you are setting the content of the memory location that `y` points to with the address of `x`. Whereas in the latter you are initializing the pointer `y` to the address of `x`. So if you remove the `*` from `*y = &x`, you will see the same output as ex1 & ex2.

Answer (score 1):

On ex3, `*y = &x;` means that you will store the address of `x` inside the memory block pointed by `y`. This is a problem since `y` is not actually pointing to anything.

Whatever `printf("address: %d\n", y);` prints, will not be a useful information.

Answer (score 1):

In declaring the type, * means "a pointer." After that it's a dereference operator. Consider:

```
int x=2;
int *y;
y=&x;
*y = x;
```

This is appropriate as far as addresses are assigned addresses, values values. However, the dereference operator gives you the contents, so *y=x doesn't last out of scope. You should treat it like a temporary. That's why if you pass *y into a function and modify it, you won't see the modifications when you print *y. You have to pass y in, that is "pass by reference." In short, &*y=&x is unstable, and not equivalent to y=&x.

See l-value and r-value in C.